# real valued random variable inclusion-exclusion

Tags: inequality, random-variables, inclusion-exclusion

I have the following question and I need help with it.
Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be realvalued Random Variables with densities and for all i,j in {1,2,3} such that $i \neq j$ we have $a_{ij} = P(X_i > X_j)$.

I must prove that min{$a_{12},a_{23},a_{31}$} $\leq 2/3$.

There is a hint to use the inclusion-exclusion principle but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\min\{a_{12},a_{23},a_{31}\}>2/3$. Then
\begin{align}
2<a_{12}+a_{23}+a_{31}&=\mathsf{P}(\{X_1>X_2\}\cup \{X_2>X_3\}\cup \{X_3>X_1\}) \\
&\quad+\mathsf{P}(X_1>X_2>X_3) \\
&\quad+\mathsf{P}(X_3>X_1>X_2) \\
&\quad+\mathsf{P}(X_2>X_3>X_1)\le 2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have a question. where did the 2 at the end come from and does the part  (a_12 ∩ a_23 ∩ a_31} = 0? because I don't see it

Comment: The events $\{X_1>X_2>X_3\}$, $\{X_3>X_1>X_2\}$, and $\{X_2>X_3>X_1\}$ are disjoint.

Comment: Ok but why are these less or equal to 2?

Comment: The first probability is at most 1, and the sum of the three last probabilities is also at most 1.